# Longest alphabetic order string

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I understand that this is repeated question but I want to find the error in my own code.
The problem is to get longest string in alphabetic order, but when it comes to  line

```
for i in range (0,len(s)+1):
     if s[i] < s[i+1]:
```

it gives me

IndexError: string index out of range.

Can you help me? Thanks in advance

Here is the full code

```
strr=''

s=input('please enter your string')

strtemp=s[0]

for i in range (0,len(s)+1):
     if s[i] < s[i+1]:

        strtemp=strtemp+s[i+1]

     if len(strr) < len(strtemp):
       strr=strtemp

print('longst string is'+ strr)
```

Comment: `i in range (0,len(s)+1)` you're ADDING 1?

Comment: You should try `for i in range (0, len(s) - 1):`, it will fix your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is loop from the first character to the n - 1.

Here your code with the fixed part:

```
import sys


strr=''

s=input('please enter your string: ')

if len(s) == 0:
    print("Your string is empty!")
    import sys
    sys.exit(1)

strtemp=s[0]

for i in range (0, len(s) - 1):
    print("chr => {}".format(s[i]))
    if s[i] < s[i+1]:
        print("i => {} | i+1 => {}".format(s[i], s[i+1]))
        strtemp=strtemp + s[i + 1]
        if len(strr) < len(strtemp):
            strr = strtemp
    else:
        strtemp = s[i+1]

    if len(strr) < len(strtemp):
        strr=strtemp

print('longest string is '+ strr)
```

There are some modifications:

- A check is done about the input length
- To fix an issue about strtemp, we are now resetting it in an else condition
- You can try, it should work well!

Comment: Thank you so much but there's still some missing point, for example when I try test cast 'ahmedwalidelmaraghy' the result should be 'delm' instead I get 'ahm'

Comment: You are right, I did put an outdated version. Here the newest one (I did try with your string and I got 'delm' as the longest one).

Comment: Thank you @Ankirama and I really appreciate your effort and patience, but still gives me unexpected answer in different test cases such as " youssefmohamedahmedalimahmoudmostafaamr" it gives me "mhmou" instead of "ahmou" similarly for "ahmedwalidelmaraghy" I get "ielm" instead of "delm" , from the results I can guess that the first element is always messed up as you can see, the first element here is always the element/ letter that is just right before the desired or expected first element

Comment: Well... My bad, I still uploaded the wrong one! Were I updated `strtemp = s[i]` to `strtemp = s[i+1]` to fix it! With this, I get 'delm' and 'ahmou'.

Answer (score 0):

At the last iteration of the loop, you compare `s[len(s)]` and `s[len(s)+1]`. In Python, indices are `0, 1, ..., len(s) - 1` (in other words, Python uses 0-based indexing). This means `s[len(s)+1]` is "out of bound", and the same applies for `s[len(s)]`. This is what provokes the error.

`s[len(s) - 1]` is the last item in s.

Therefore, you should range from 0 to `len(s) - 1`.

Comment: Thank that's solved an issue but can I rephrase my question because I still can't get the longest string?                                                                                                         ```strr=''

s=input('please enter your string')

strtemp=s[0]

for n in range (0,len(s)-1):
    
     if len(strr) < len(strtemp):
                     strr=strtemp
                     
     if s[n] < s[n+1]:
        strtemp=strtemp+s[n+1]
     else:
         strtemp=s[n]
       
                   
       
       
print('longst string is  '+ strr) ```

Comment: @YoussefEl-Maraghy check my answer, I did fix your issue.